# How to get name of the stored procedure in iBatis + Spring

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

In our DAO objects we call stored procedures simply like below:

```
getSqlMapClientTemplateOltp().queryForList("mysps.myspname", paramMap);
```

the above calls the stored procedures with the supplied parameters. The stored procedure stays in a sql mapping file called `mysps` like below

```
<procedure id="myspname" parameterMap="myspnameCall">
 {call get_reports_smry (?,?,?,?,?) }
</procedure>
```

**Question:**

How can I get the corresponding actual SP name as a String so that I can put that in my logger since its a hassle to find out which SP was executed without going to the actual sqlmap.

I want something like

```
//this brings back "get_reports_smry"
getSqlMapClientTemplateOltp().getStatementAsString("mysps.myspname");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [p6spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/), it can log all your database interactions including the sproc names and parameters.